# Rotate TextButton with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, matrix-transform

I have a textButton and I want to place it on the screen rotated by 90deg.

For some reason all methods for rotation(rotate(), setRotationAngle() and so on) assosiated with TextButton object do not work properly.

So I've implemented new class extending the TextButton and overriding draw() method:

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
     Matrix4 rotationMatrix = new Matrix4();
     Matrix4 oldMatrix = batch.getTransformMatrix();
     rotationMatrix.idt();
     rotationMatrix.rotate(new Vector3(this.getX(),this.getY()+this.getHeight(),0),rotationAngle);
     batch.setTransformMatrix(rotationMatrix);
     super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
     batch.setTransformMatrix(oldMatrix);
}
```

Where `rotationAngle` equals to 90.0. And for some reason button isn't rotated by 90degress, but for some unknown amount of degrees.

[image]

**UPD**

After I switched back to TextButton object and did :

```
newGame.setTransform(true);
newGame.rotate(90);
```

It almost worked meaning that text in the button was rotated corrently, but the background of the button stayed on it's spot:

[image]

So my question is: Why does this happen and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented rotating Widgets according to the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Rotation_and_scale)

Here is my code:

```
Table buttonContainer = new Table(skin);
buttonContainer.setTransform(true);
buttonContainer.add(button1);
buttonContainer.row().pad(10);
buttonContainer.add(button2);
rotatingActor = buttonContainer;
```

and then:

```
rotatingActor.setRotation(newDegree);
```

All the click handlers etc. work as expected even if the widget are rotated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [project issue](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1435#c2) that is closed as won't fix.

> None of the UI elements in scene2d can be rotated due to the fact that clipping is implemented via scissoring. Scissoring requires axis aligned rectangles.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't mean that rotation by matrix transformations could not be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation methods on existing Actors should work.  Probably worth asking another question to track that issue down.

I see at least two problems:

1. the default batch transorm matrix probably isn't the identity matrix.  Maybe initialize `rotationMatrix` as a copy of `oldMatrix`?
2. You're rotating around a really arbitrary vector (draw a line from the origin -- in the bottom left to the top-left corner of your button).  Try `Vector3(0, 1, 0)`.

Comment: Rotation with other vectors didn't help. But TextButton object's method setTrasform() helped to rotate the text of the button, but not the button itself(P.S I've updated the question)